# InfluxDB tables being dropped randomly?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a table where values are being written in every few hours. However, the table is randomly being dropped after ~ 1 - 2 hours (not consistent, sometimes 65 minutes, sometimes 90minutes) and grafana will just show ‘no data’. If I change the query to another table and try to change back, the table name disappears from the drop-down list.

I have my retention policy set as ‘autogen’, so the data should not be cleared out for a week.

Comment: What's your setup? Docker?

Comment: @FWeidinger Yea, InfluxDB and grafana are in separate docker containers.